# Weird error 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, exception

here is the error I am getting :

```
System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233082
Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
InnerException:
```

code Update:
here is my code

```
void WriteGraph(int[] vData)
    {
        string tempWrite = "";
        try
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < vData.Length;)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    tempWrite = tempWrite + vData[i] + ",";
                    y++;
                }
                File.AppendAllText(name2, tempWrite);
            }
         
           File.AppendAllText(name2, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            AppendTextBox(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

it fails at  `tempWrite = tempWrite + vData[i] + ","`.

not that is in a loop so it does write some values to the file.

I open the file in Excel and it goes from A to  LW

before it died ...

the question is why ?
here is the loop :

```
void PlotSpectrum(int []vData)
    {
        ArrayList listDataSource = new ArrayList();

        // Populate the list with records. 
        for (int i = 0; i < vData.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteGraph(Convert.ToString(vData[i]));
            listDataSource.Add(new Graph_Class(i, vData[i]));
        }

        // Bind the chart to the list. 
        ChartControl myChart = chartControl1;
        myChart.DataSource = listDataSource;

        // Create a series, and add it to the chart. 
        Series series1 = new Series("Spectrum", ViewType.Line);
        myChart.Series.Add(series1);

        // Adjust the series data members. 
         series1.ArgumentDataMember = "X";
       series1.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Y" });

        // Access the view-type-specific options of the series. 
        ((LineSeriesView)series1.View).ColorEach = true;
        series1.LegendTextPattern = "{A}";
        try
        {
            //myChart.Update();
         //   myChart.Refresh();
        }catch(Exception err)
        {
            AppendTextBox(err.Message.ToString());
            print("Error in Graph: ", DateTime.Now.ToString(), err.Message.ToString());
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: try debugging and watch the variable - should give you a clue.

Comment: ok so I am not sure what to watch. VData has data in it . It is size 1024, so I do not want to go though all of the points .

Comment: ok it looks like it Dies at i = 305

Comment: ok the second time it died at I = 380

Comment: has anyone seen anything like this before ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104845/4180382

Comment: 'ArrayList' is an obsolete collection type. Can't you use List?

Answer (score 1):

The same thing is happening for me, but it only throws this exception when a yarn rebuild finishes (front-end is React). I am using IIS Express to run locally. I wonder if it doesn't like that the files are changing while the app is running.

This seems to fix it:

Go to Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, Web Projects; and check "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects".

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happened in Service Fabric startup before it has a chance to begin running. The exception shows up in the Event Viewer rather than VS.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because something failed before throw ExecutionEngineException.
I faced this issue (typing Japanese characters in TextBox on WPF app), I solved activating **Common Language Runtime Exceptions in Exceptions Settings in VS**
and checking the values of each runtime exception(before get crash) and I found a null value in one of the variables in a previous method but the crash was thrown many seconds after that.
You can find a deep explanation here: [Why this code throws System.ExecutionEngineException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102881/why-this-code-throws-system-executionengineexception)