# Azure Durable function is crashing out

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, out-of-memory, azure-durable-functions

I have Azure Durable functions with Event Grid as a trigger point which is pointing to blob storage.

I have 8 activity functions and 1 orchestrator.

Based on the file types I receive one of the activity function is executed.

However I keep receiving the crashing message as in the image.

[image: Crashing Function App Image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message that you have shared is pointing that function failed with "System.ExecutionEngineException"

Generally , `System.ExecutionEngineException` exception is thrown when the CLR *detects* that something has gone horribly wrong.
This can happen some considerable time after the problem occurred. This is because the exception is usually a result of corruption of internal data structures - the CLR discovers that something has got into a state that makes no sense. It throws an [uncatchable exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104845/15968720) because it's not safe to proceed.

Looking at the stack trace that you have mentioned in the screen shot more over exception is pointing out  `DurableTask.AzureStorage.TimeoutHandler+ <ExecuteWithTimeout` issue.

You can use  memory dump generated by the [Proactive  Crash Monitoring tool](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/01/Proactive-Crash-Monitoring-in-Azure-App-Service.html#:%7E:text=Proactive%20Crash%20Monitoring%20is%20a%20feature%20of%20Azure,in%20App%20Service%20Diagnostics%20for%20Windows%20web%20apps.)
to identify the function crash & associated crashing thread call stack.

please create a technical support ticket by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) wherein technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue or open a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) Community.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is aware of it, and it's currently as designed. It shouldn't affect your apps. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1965#issuecomment-931637193